# ios simulator won't stay horizontal even when landscape mode is ticked

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

I'm developing a swift project with `XCode` and I need my app to run only in `landscape` mode. I ticked the option like it shows here:

[image]

but still, when I launch the app the simulator stays in portrait.

**I know i can rotate it with command + left or right but I'd prefer XCode to do that for me.**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to set it too in your info.plist key `Supported interface orientations`:

[image]

Comment: Yeah, i already checked that option and it still didn't work then i rebooted my Mac and now the simulator works the way i wanted... weird. Thanks anyway.